# CakePHP pagination ellipses not showing

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

There are 11 pages and I am using `modulus => 8` which shows 9 page numbers at a time.

Following is the code:

```
echo $this->Paginator->numbers(
    array('modulus' => 8,
        'separator' => false,
        'before' => '',
        'after' => '',
        'tag' => 'li',
        'class' => false,
        'currentClass' => 'disabled',
        'currentTag' => 'a'
    )
);
```

The problem is that ellipses `...` is not appearing in the pagination numbers. I am using cakephp 2.4.xx and in the documentation its written that ellipses appear automatically.

Please guide me how to bring the `...` in the pagination numbers.

Comment: What _do_ you get - add the rendered html to the question.

Comment: @AD7six I simply get numbers from 1 - 9 with no `....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it works only when 'first' or 'last' are set to an integer value.

i.e.:

```
echo $this->Paginator->numbers(
    array('modulus' => 8,
        'separator' => false,
        'before' => '',
        'after' => '',
        'tag' => 'li',
        'class' => false,
        'currentClass' => 'disabled',
        'currentTag' => 'a',
        'first' => 3,
        'last' => 3,
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. Can you please explain its working...?